# E-shop product categories align

Tags: html, css, typo3

I have a e-shop project in TYPO3 CMS. I have problem with formatting list of products (when you click on all products). Beginnings of categories are spaced differently. Here I have a picture.

[image]

Here is, how my html part of the site looks:

```
 <form method="post" action="###FORM_URL###" name="shopForm">
 <div class="productCategory"> 
 <!-- ###ITEM_CATEGORY### begin -->



  <h2><!--###LINK_ITEM### begin-->###CATEGORY_TITLE###<!--###LINK_ITEM### end--></h2>

  <h3>###CATEGORY_NOTE###</h3>



  <!-- ###ITEM_CATEGORY### end -->

  </div>
  <!-- ###ITEM_LIST### begin -->
  <!-- ###ITEM_SINGLE### begin-->
  <div class="listitem boxShadow">

    <h3><!--###LINK_ITEM###-->###PRODUCT_TITLE###<!--###LINK_ITEM###--></h3>

    <div class="productImage">
        ###PRODUCT_IMAGE1###
    </div>
        </td>

    <p class="price">###PRODUCT_PRICE### &euro;</p>
    <p class="text">###PRODUCT_SUBTITLE###</p>

      <p>
        <table class="right">
          <td><INPUT size="3" maxlength="4" type="text" name="###FIELD_NAME###" id="###FIELD_NAME###" value="###FIELD_QTY###" class="amount"/></td>
         <td> <input  type="image"  src="fileadmin/templates/images/basket_add.png" name="basket" class="inputimage" alt="Kúpiť" onClick="if(!document.getElementById('###FIELD_NAME###').value!=''){document.getElementById('###FIELD_NAME###').value=1;}; submit();"/></td>
        </table>

      </p>


  </div>
  <!-- ###ITEM_SINGLE### end -->
  <!-- ###ITEM_LIST### end -->


  <!-- ###ITEM_CATEGORY_AND_ITEMS### end -->

  </form>

  <br clear="all" >
```

What could be wrong? I spent 4 days searching for solution before I decided to ask you guys. Thank you

EDIT:
CSS styles for this form:

```
 .productCategory h2{font-size:15px;}
 .listitem .text{height:32px; overflow:hidden}
 .listitem h3{height: 30px; overflow:hidden; font-size:13px; }
 #tt-products-list-1 form {float:left; display: inline-block;}
 .right {border-spacing: 10px 50px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSS issue, either with `vertical-align: top` or with `display: inline-block`

Would you mind posting your css for this part of your app?

Comment: I have added some css styles related to this part of html code. By the way inline-block didnt solve my issue.